# SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

I'm doing the rock, paper, scissors JavaScript class on CodeCademy,

I'm stuck on one of the modules, keep getting "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

It's really weird! The prompt won't run unless I remove all the curly brackets(`{}`)  ....But I need curly brackets in an if / else if / else statement.

If I remove the first `{`, then the error message comes up:
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token }". So it's just noticed the next curly bracket in line.

Here's my code:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

//All curly brackets are below this point

if (computerChoice >0, computerChoice <= .33) {
    computerChoice = rock;
} else if (computerChoice > .33, computerChoice < .66) {
    computerChoice = paper;
} else (computerChoice => .66, computerChoice <= 1) {
    computerChoice = scissors;
}
```

Comment: Look at the line of code generating the error.

Comment: Unrelated: I strongly strongly doubt that your conditions work as you expect. Only last one is actually "used"

Comment: *But I need curly brackets in an if / else if / else statement.* Actually, you don't. Also, just curious, but this syntax `if (condition1, condition2)`, did you learn it somewhere, or just guess at it? Why are you checking for `>0`, when it will always be? In the next condition, why are you checking for `> 0.33`, when you already know it is? Why are you checking for `<=1` when it obviously always is?

Comment: Consider using a linter like jsHint or esLint to help you find mistakes.

Comment: Hey thank you everyone for the helpful feedback, and sorry if I didn't format my question the best or missed some newb errors, I'm new to all this.  @AD7six I'm editing in webstorm (as well as on codecademy website), how do I check which line of code is generating the error?

Comment: @torazaburo  You've highlighted a number of mistakes I've made, so thanks.  I didn't know that if / else if / else statement could be made without the use of { } these.  Can you show how?        For the Syntax:                        if (condition1, condition2)          ..that was my mistake, I'm used to defining parameters with an in and an out point, not necessary  to define two points if one is implied in JavaScript, I guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a comma so separate conditionals, use `&&`. Also, instead of the last `else if`, just remove the conditional altogether because it is unnecessary (*`Math.random()` does not go above 1*). Finally, unless `rock`, `paper`, and `scissors` are defined elsewhere, you need to make them strings:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

//All curly brackets are below this point

if (computerChoice <= .33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice < .66) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
```

Comment: As long as you're fixing up the code, why not remove the unnecessary `> .33` check?

Comment: @torazaburo true, thanks for catching that

Comment: @A.J. Thank you for demonstrating a correct version of what I was trying to do,  I also for got to throw some "quotes" around my rock, paper, and scissors strings.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `if` in the last `else if` clause. (Though in this case as A.J. rightly notes, no further comparisons are necessary; if you make it to that last `else`, then the condition has to hold.)

Also the pairs of comparisons need to be separated by `&&` not commas.

In this:

```
else (computerChoice => .66, computerChoice <= 1) {
```

the parenthesized expression is treated as a simple expression statement. The syntax error happens because it's not followed by a semicolon, and so that dangling `{` does not make sense to the parser.

Answer (score 2):

You don't combine the conditions using a `,` but with the conditional operators. Also, you cannot add a condition for the `else` statement. Use the following:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");

var computerChoice = Math.random();

//All curly brackets are below this point

if (computerChoice >0 && computerChoice <= .33) {
    computerChoice = rock;
} else if (computerChoice > .33 && computerChoice < .66) {
    computerChoice = paper;
} else {
    computerChoice = scissors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the ternary operator to save yourself mental anguish.

```
computerChoice = computerChoice < 1/3 ? rock : computerChoice < 2/3 ? paper : scissors;
```

Comment: I need to use ternary more

Comment: @torazaburo Thank you for the sharp editing and simple solutions.